# Error when trying to run an admob inhouse ad: "ad type not supported"

Tags: android, admob

I've been using in house admob ads for a long time to promote my Android apps, but since a few days ago I cannot run the ads.

When trying to run them from the admob website, they will stay stopped and an error message appears: "*One or more of your ad group types is no longer supported and cannot be run. Please move this ad group to Google AdWords. Find out how [here]*[1](http://support.google.com/adwords/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2663346)."

That link announces that web ads should be placed in AdWords. That's great, but all my ad group types are Android App Download, which is supposed to remain in admob. And it is an inhouse ad, which does not even exist in AdWords as far as I know.

I thought I had found a workaround: recreating the in house campaign allowed me to run ads once again for a few days. But today I'm receiving that very same error again when trying to run a stopped ad.

Any piece of advice? Are your inhouse Android App Download ads running fine as usual?

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  I'm thinking that it is a bug, and they'll fix it when they get back to work.

Comment: Have you been able to resolve the problem?

Comment: The admob support team is aware, I'm waiting for a reply...

Comment: By the way; how can you manage to contact them. There seem to be no mail address around. Just the contact page for specific subjects only.

Comment: Right, write to the AdWords support (after all the error message refers to AdWords). They will eventually scale the problem to the admob staff.

Answer (score 0):

OK This seems to be working again.

I started from scratch.

Under: Ad Group Goal you need to put Android App Download.

In the Ad Information,

URL: market://details?id=com.yourdomain.yourpackage

Display URL:  play.google.com

=============================
If I'm remembering correctly, I wasn't using market:// in the Ad information URL, I was using the full path to my app like this

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mydomain.mypackage

That is the only thing I know of that I'm doing differently.  Either they fixed something, or that was the issue.

Comment: That's exactly the workaround I mention in my question. But, at least in my case, it broke again itself in a couple of days. Hope you have more luck though :)